# XQuery/Xpath referring to xml elements with no namespace, in a namespace environment

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

In Xquery 3.1 (under eXist-DB 4.7) I receive xml data like this, with no namespace:

```
 <edit-request  id="TC9999">
    <title-collection>foocolltitle</title-collection> 
    <title-exempla>fooextitle</title-exempla> 
    <title-short>fooshorttitle</title-short> 
 </edit-request>
```

This is assigned to a variable `$content` and this statement:

```
let $collid := $content/edit-request/@id
```

...correctly returns: `TC9999`

Now,  I need to actually transform all the data in `$content` into a TEI xml document.

I first need to get some info from an existing TEI file, so I assigned another variable:

```
 let $oldcontent := doc(concat($globalvar:URIdata,$collid,"/",$collid,".xml"))
```

And then I create the new TEI document, referring to both `$content` and `$oldcontent`:

```
 let $xml :=  <listBibl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" 
                type="collection" 
                xml:id="{$collid}">
                   <bibl>
                      <idno type="old_sql_id">{$oldcontent//tei:idno[@type="old_sql_id"]/text()}</idno>
                      <title type="collection">{$content//title-exempla/text()}</title>
                   </bibl>
              </listBibl>
```

The references to the TEI namespace in `$oldcontent` come through, but to my surprise the references to `$content` (no namespace) don't show up:

```
 <listBibl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" 
            type="collection" 
            xml:id="TC9999">
    <bibl>
      <idno type="old_sql_id">1</idno>
      <title type="collection"/>
    </bibl>
 </listBibl>
```

The question is: how do I refer to the non-namespace elements in `$content` in the context of `let $xml=...`?

Nb: the Xquery document has a declaration at the top (as it is the principle namespace of virtually all the documents):

```
  declare namespace tei = "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence you are asking how to write an XPath expression to select nodes in an empty namespace in a context where the default element namespace is non-empty. One of the most direct solutions is to use the "URI plus local-name syntax" for writing QNames. Here is an example:

```
xquery version "3.1";

let $x := <x><y>Jbrehr</y></x>
return
  <p xmlns="foo">Hey there,
    { $x/Q{}y => string() }!</p>
```

If instead of `$x/Q{}y` the example had used the more common form of the path expression, `$x/y`, its result would have been an empty sequence, since the local name `y` used to select the `<y>` element specifies no namespace and thus inherits the `foo` element namespace from its context. By using the "URI plus local-name syntax", though, we are able to specify the empty namespace we are looking for.

For more information on this, see the XPath 3.1 specification's discussion of expanded QNames: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#doc-xpath31-EQName.